# Devising a method to arrive at a square only being able to move right and up

Tags: game-theory

I was recently presented with a problem where I have a 10x10 grid and a marker that starts at position (1, 1). Two players are able to manipulate the marker by moving it as far right, or (exclusive) as far up as they would like once on each of their respective turns. The player to finally move the marker into the space at (10, 10) would be the winner.

How would I develop a strategy such that either player can guarantee victory for themselves. I seem to suspect that the player that moves second has the advantage. Is there a way I can mathematically represent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Show that the second player can always move to a point on the diagonal (i.e., one with both coordinates the same).

Comment: As often happens, actually sitting down to try to play the game quickly illustrates the winning strategy. :-)

Comment: What do you mean always move to a diagonal point?

Comment: @Brian: Yep. I used to introduce it in the form of two-heap Nim to a liberal arts class, and a significant number of students would discover the ‘balancing’ strategy.

Comment: @user264931: Which part of that statement don’t you understand? I did explain what a diagonal point is. By *always move* I mean that no matter what the first player does, you can always respond with a move that puts the piece back on the diagonal. What happens if you keep doing this?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am confused in that on their respective turns, each player can only move in one direction.

Comment: @user264931: I know; that’s precisely what makes the strategy that I’ve suggested work. For instance, if on his first move the first player moves it $2$ places to the right, you can move it ... how? ... to get it back on the diagonal.

Comment: Player 1 begins at a diagonal point, namely, $(1,1)$. So player 1 must move to $(1,a)$ or to $(a,1)$. Then player 2 moves to $(a,a)$.

Comment: @user264931: To make it more explicit, the first player can either move to $(a, 1)$, or to $(1, a)$, where $a > 1$.  The second player then just moves to $(a, a)$.  Then the first player can only move to $(b, a)$ or to $(a, b)$, where $b > a$.  The second player then just moves to $(b, b)$.  Since each round increases the coordinates of the position, the first player will eventually be forced to move to $(10, 9)$ or to $(9, 10)$, whereupon the second player moves to $(10, 10)$.

Comment: Right, okay, that makes complete sense to me. Thanks!